# Can't see subreport in the Report Manager

Tags: reporting-services, subreport, reportmanager

I've been following [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337460(SQL.90).aspx) (lesson 6) in order to build and deploy a sample report with an embedded subreport which reads its parameters' values from the parent report. This subreport is embedded in one of the group rows of the report's table, and both share the same datasource. Additionally, detail rows appear collapsed until the user presses the (+) button for each group of data in the table.

The report works great when I preview it at the Business Intelligence Development Studio (by the way, SQL 2005 Express edition) but **when I deploy it and try to see in the Report Manager, the subreport is not shown**. And, if I press the (+) button, the following message appears:

> *Some parameters or credentials have not been specified*

Does anybody has the slightest idea of what I am doing wrong? Why does it works perfectly in the Report Viewer embedded in Visual Studio but not in the Report Manager web app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm beginning to think this could be an issue with the browser. I'm currently using Internet Explorer 8 Beta and I'm also experiencing weird behavior from the Report Manager. I've tried with Google Chrome and Firefox 3 and, although the navigation is not as smooth as I like, the problem seems fixed.

Comment: That would be very interesting if that's the case. I do not have IE8 so I can not test that for you. I would probably make a post on the SQL Server Reporting Services Forum and see if anyone else can confirm that. http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowForum.aspx?ForumID=82&SiteID=1

Comment: @Erikk Ross - was this ever resolved? I've just had it happen to a client with a single report (no subreport) - as soon as you expand a table group the 'some parameters or credentials have not been specified' error pops up. Its the strangest thing. Report works fine in Report Builder on the client machine. They too are using IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Does the subreport use the same Data Source as the parent report? If not, be sure to check the data source of the subreport to make sure it is correct. Check in Report Manager, not your local copy.

Answer (score 1):

it happens when you use IE8 as a report browser. I faced same issue and when I tested on chrome it worked fine .

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be related, but I had a similar problem some time ago (except that in my case the reports were accessed through a custom web page) and it turned out we had an older version of the report viewer control (the version that came with Sql 2005 RTM). After upgrading to the latest version the issue went away.